# python list.append with for loop

Tags: list, loops, for-loop, append

I was wondering if it is possible to add a for loop in a append function.

used code now:

```
for Master_ii in ExcelSheet_IO.iter_rows(min_row=3):
  if Master_ii[0].value != '': #Collect column A to S from excel in to Imported_Variables (A=[0]-X=[18])    
Imported_Variables.append([Master_ii[0].value,Master_ii[1].value,Master_ii[2].value,Master_ii[3].value,Master_ii[4].value,Master_ii[5].value,Master_ii[6].value,Master_ii[7].value,Master_ii[8].value,Master_ii[9].value,Master_ii[10].value,Master_ii[11].value,Master_ii[12].value,Master_ii[13].value,Master_ii[14].value,Master_ii[15].value,Master_ii[16].value,Master_ii[17].value,Master_ii[18].value])
```

what i want is (something like this):

```
for Master_ii in ExcelSheet_IO.iter_rows(min_row=3):
   if Master_ii[0].value != '':
            #Collect column A to S from excel in to Imported_Variables (A=[0]-X=[18])
            Imported_Variables.append([(for i in range(0,18): Master_ii[i].value)])
```

Comment: ExcelSheet_IO.iter_rows(min_row=3). what is in this ?

Comment: That for loop is for collecting a table from excel. where the start row is row 3.